# what to use in Android API 8 when TextToSpeechService not exist

Tags: android

what to use in Android API 8 when TextToSpeechService not exist.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeechService.html

can i use something else? is there workaround?

Comment: how about    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.options_failure, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: i don't understand your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [TextToSpeech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getEngines%28%29) API from Android 1.6.    [This](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html) tutorial should be helpful.